# Converting Expected value to integrals and differentiating

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Can you suggest me how to convert the following expected value function in to an integral and differentiate it with respect to $a$.

\begin{equation*}
g \equiv E \left[ \max \left( a + x-b,0 \right) \times 1_{\{c+y \leq b \}} \right]
\end{equation*} 
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} $ and the term after the multiplication sign is an indicator function. $x$ and $y$ are both random variables with continuous probability distribution functions $f_x$ and $f_y$.

Comment: Are the random variables $x$ and $y$ independent, uncorrelated, or neither?

Comment: @rajb245 For my purpose $x$ and $y$ are not independent.

Comment: Do you know the joint distribution of both variables simultaneously?  That is, do you know the probability density of $X=x$ and $Y=y$ simultaneously?  Or do you have some explicit relationship between them?

Comment: @rajb245 I neither have explicit relationship between them, nor defined their joint density. You may consider either to define a continuous joint probability density, or define a random variable $t\equiv x-y$ if it is useful for the purpose.

Comment: It should be pointed out that $$\frac{dg}{da} = \mathbb{E}\left[ 1_{\{a+x\geq b\}}1_{\{c+y\leq b\}}\right] = \mathbb{P}(a+x\geq b, c+y\leq b).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation of a function of two random variables is written as the following integral

$$
E[h(X,Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \;dxdy
$$

The function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint density of the random variables.  I'm going to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, in which case the joint density is the product of the marginals, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. In your case, $h(x,y)=\max(a+x-b,0)\times 1_{\{c+y\leq b\}}$, so the integral becomes

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \max(a+x-b,0) 1_{\{c+y\leq b\}} f_X(x)f_Y(y) \;dxdy
$$

Now, when $y>b-c$, the indicator function is zero and the integrand is zero.  Similarly, when $x<b-a$,  the $\max$ term is also zero and the integrand is zero.  These two facts allow us to absorb the effects of those two terms into the integration limits

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{b-c}\int_{b-a}^\infty (a+x-b) f_X(x)f_Y(y) \;dxdy
$$

The $y$ integration can be carried out in terms of the cumulative density function (CDF) for $Y$, $F_Y(y)$, since the integrand does not depend on $y$
$$
F_Y(b-c)\int_{b-a}^\infty (a+x-b) f_X(x) \;dx
$$
Break that up into two pieces, one involving $a-b$ and the other with just the $x$.  The first piece can also be written in terms of a CDF, $F_X(x)$

$$
F_Y(b-c)\left((a-b)(1-F_X(x))+\int_{b-a}^\infty x f_X(x) \;dx\right)
$$

Now you just have to differentiate w.r.t. $a$.

**Edit** 
OP says the variables are not independent.  In that case, I think you'd just need the joint density explicitly and slog through this integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{b-c}\int_{b-a}^\infty (a+x-b) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \;dxdy
$$

The problem is that in general, even if you know the marginal densities, you need more information to form the joint density.